# Finding the laplace transform of a series involving a dirac delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the problem:
Suppose that $y''+y=f(t); y(0)=0, y'(0)=0.$

Find the solution to the IVP when $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{20}(-1)^{k+1}\delta(t-k\pi)$.

What is the process of setting up a laplace transform of a series?  I know I can solve this if I can get it to look familiar, as I have never seen anything like this before.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can take the Laplace transform of the series of delta functions term by term, since the Laplace transform is linear.  We have:

$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\delta(t - k\pi)dt = e^{-sk\pi}$

since the shifted delta function applied to a function under an infinite integral "picks out" the value of the integrand at the shift point.

Then in the S domain you just have the sum:

$-\sum_{k=1}^{20}(-e^{-s\pi})^k$

which can be expressed in closed-form using the relation for a geometric series.